# A tricky usage of "of". "Timewalking version of Ghostworld Chestguard should no longer incorrectly have Spirit."

Tags: prepositions

> Timewalking version of Ghostworld Chestguard should no longer incorrectly have Spirit.

I ran across this sentence when I checked out the fixes notes of WOW ( an online game), I know this sentence wants to convey that the Ghostworld Chestguard belonging to Timewalking version has been fixed the problem. The whole sentence and the subject should emphasize the Chestguard other than version. Thus in my mind, I will say `The Ghostworld Chestguard of the Timewalking version` instead of what it actually used as the subject.

Basically it's a problem of `of` usage.
My understanding of `of` can be seen below:
a family of fools ( of = containing )
the fool of the team ( of = belonging )
Therefore, I assume the subject of the sentence I run across should be " The Ghostworld Chestguard of the Timewalking version", `of` means belonging.

Comment: Actually, it appears that the problem is with *version*. The quoted sentence is entirely grammatical; your rewording does not mean quite the same, and is only grammatical if you use a specialised meaning for *version* (which may well be possible within WoW: I do not know).

Comment: but what is the difference between my rewording and the original?

Comment: It must be 'a version *of* something'; so 'The Timewalking version of the Chestguard' is normal: 'The Chestguard of the Timewalking version' I believe to mean 'The Chestguard in the Timewalking version of World of Warcraft'. The difference is probably unimportant here, but not in all contexts.

Answer (score 1):

"Of" has many different uses.  It is the second most common English word, and its use overlaps a lot with use of [genitive case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case).  You can see [many excellent example quotations using "of" on Wiktionary.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of)

One use you mention is expressing composition (#5 on Wiktionary), as in "a family of fools".  This is somewhat different than the next use.

Certain words typically take "of X" as an [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(linguistics)).  For example, the word "[version](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/version)" specifically takes an argument as "***version of X***":

> Microsoft has released a new version of Windows.
>
> That church uses the King James Version of the bible.
>
> They improved the Timewalking version of Ghostworld Chestguard. Which version of Ghostworld Chestguard did you start with?

Comment: I kind of see your point, krubo. But what the difference between  "That church uses the bible of the King James Version ." and "That church uses the King James Version of the bible." Can I use my rewording in this case?

Comment: I keep rewording like this due to the example I can relate to such as "a bike of Tom" , Tom modifies the bike, meaning Tom's bike and it emphasize "bike", "of Tom" is more like an adjective.  Therefore, I put "KJ version" behind bible "a bible of KJ version" to express: KJ version's bible, emphasizing bible instead of version.  Same idea goes back to my original question  posted here.

Comment: From a syntactic point of view, "version" is the [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) in the examples I wrote.  Although you could say that "KJ version" is more like an adjective in terms of meaning, it is actually the KJ version that is emphasized.  The main point of the sentence was to specify which version the church uses. Likewise, the main point about Ghostworld Chestguard is to specify which version has the incorrect Spirit removed.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're seeking an intuitive answer, rather than a syntactic one. (For a syntactic answer, see my other answer.)

Intuitively, when I read "Timewalking version of Ghostworld Chestguard", I interpret that there are many different Ghostworld Chestguards, or that the Ghostworld Chestguards exist in many different versions, and that the Timewalking version is one such version.

Intuitively, when I read "Ghostworld Chestguard of the Timewalking version", it sounds a bit odd, but I can interpret that the Timewalking version is a setting that has multiple components, and that Ghostworld Chestguard is one such component.  Although I don't know WoW, I wonder if a better phrasing for this meaning might be, "In the Timewalking version of the game, Ghostworld Chestguard should no longer incorrectly have spirit."